# connect to mariadb using aws lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a layer where I have installed `mariadb` and `requests`. The layer file is a zip archive of `python\lib\python3.9\site-packages`. Inside the `site-packages`, it looks like:

```
├── bin
├── certifi
├── certifi-2022.6.15.2.dist-info
├── charset_normalizer
├── charset_normalizer-2.1.1.dist-info
├── google
├── idna
├── idna-3.3.dist-info
├── mariadb
├── mariadb-1.1.4.dist-info
├── protobuf-3.20.1.dist-info
├── protobuf-3.20.1-py3.10-nspkg.pth
├── requests
├── requests-2.28.1.dist-info
├── urllib3
└── urllib3-1.26.12.dist-info
```

The AWS lambda function for now only has following code:

```
import requests
from mariadb import connect
```

When I test it, I get the following error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'mariadb._mariadb'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "########",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code or what your problem is? What have you tried so far to address the problem, and what results did that have?

Comment: @JohnAlexINL, the code is just importing the two libraries. Not sure how one can reproduce it locally without AWS lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get `mariadb` library to work with `lambda` functions. I suspect installing just the python package alone is not enough as it also requires the `MariaDB Connector/C`. I eventually replaced `mariadb` with [`PyMySQL`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make it work.